# Default format for numeric fields in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql installations on two different unix VMs. The first mysql is 5.5, the second 5.7.
On each mysql instance I have a database which contains a `table X`, with fields of type `DOUBLE`.

The problem: 
Fields of type double are displayed with different decimal separators on each of the instances.

The query:

```
select * from X
```

on mysql 5.5 will return the numbers formatted with a colon as a decimal separator, e.g.

```
1,1/1,2/1,3/0,5120912/1,121201
```

on the other installation a dot will be used instead:

```
1.1/1.2/1.3/0.5120912/1.121201
```

Which mysql or os parameter affects the default decimal separator? I am not able and i don't want to use any CAST functions. I just need all fields of type double returned with a comma by default.

I tried changing the `LOCALE (LC_NUMERIC)` setting on the OS level but it did not help.

Comment: Mysql **server** knows only one decimal separator: point. The various **clients** may override this setting and display the results differently, but this is client specific and not mysql specific. If comma was allowed as a decimal separator, then it would be difficult for mysql to disntinguish between a decimal number and a list consisting of two integers.